# Kubuntu 14.10 kernel panic

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, kubuntu, 14.10

I downloaded and burned the Kubuntu 14.10 amd64 iso.
My laptop was running Kubuntu 14.04 amd64; it is a 4-year-old Dell Studio 17.
When booting from the DVD, there is a kernel panic, unable to mount root VFS, I don't think the kernel can find the image to load on the disk to bootstrap. Same thing happens when selecting the recovery option from Grub. What's the deal?

Comment: Welcome to AU! How did you create the bootable DVD? Did you check the integrity of the image?

Answer (score 0):

As you are booting from a DVD, the DVD itself may either be damaged or corrupted, or the `.iso` file you downloaded corrupted when downloading. Try re-downloading it and burning it to another disk at a lower speed, and if possible, enable disk verification in your disk burner application's settings. This method should produce a working bootable disk.